# HashSet.Remove not working with EqualityComparer

Tags: c#, hashset

I am expecting a HashSet that has been created with a specified EqualityComparer to use that comparer on a Remove operation. Especially since the Contains operations returns true!

Here is the code I am using:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Allocation> Allocations { get { return _allocations; } }
private ICollection<Allocation> _allocations; 

public Activity(IActivitySubject subject) {    // constructor
    ....
    _allocations = new HashSet<Allocation>(new DurationExcludedEqualityComparer());
}

public virtual void ClockIn(Allocation a)
{
    ...
    if (_allocations.Contains(a)) 
        _allocations.Remove(a);
    _allocations.Add(a);
}
```

Below is some quick and dirty LINQ that gets me the logic I want, but I am guessing the HashSet remove based on the EqualityComparer would be significantly faster.

```
public virtual void ClockIn(Allocation a)
{
    ...
    var found = _allocations.Where(x => x.StartTime.Equals(a.StartTime) && x.Resource.Equals(a.Resource)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (found != null)
    {
            if (!Equals(found.Duration, a.Duration))
            {
                found.UpdateDurationTo(a.Duration);
            }
    }
    else
    {
            _allocations.Add(a);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest why the Remove would fail when the Contains succeeds?

Cheers,
Berryl

=== EDIT === the comparer

```
public class DurationExcludedEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<Allocation>
{
    public override bool Equals(Allocation lhs, Allocation rhs)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, rhs)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs)) return true;

        return 
            lhs.StartTime.Equals(rhs.StartTime) &&
            lhs.Resource.Equals(rhs.Resource) && 
            lhs.Activity.Equals(rhs.Activity);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Allocation obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;
        unchecked
        {
            var result = 17;
            result = (result * 397) ^ obj.StartTime.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ (obj.Resource != null ? obj.Resource.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (obj.Activity != null ? obj.Activity.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

=== UPDATE - FIXED ===

Well, the good news is that HashSet is not broken and works exactly as it should. The bad news, for me, is how incredibly stupid I can be when not being able to see the forest while examining the leaves on the trees!

The answer is actually in the posted code above, if you look at the class creating & owning the HashSet, and then taking another look at the Comparer to find out what is wrong with it. Easy points for the first person to spot it.

Thanks to all who looked at the code!

Comment: Post `DurationExcludedEqualityComparer`.

Comment: I would guess your implementation of equality in `DurationExcludedEqualityComparer` is suspect.

Comment: What does your `Allocation` class (and also whatever `Resource` and `Activity` refer to) look like?

Comment: Just a (hopefully helpful) side note, I've noticed many people do this, you don't need to test `ReferenceEquals` against null, you only need to do it with the two references and `ReferenceEquals` takes care of it for you, null cases included, returning false if one of them is null reference. If both are null references however, true is returned.  I think even ReSharper insists on doing dual checks, but Microsoft themselves say this is not necessary. So only the last of the three reference checks you do is actually needed.

Comment: @Skurmedel: From an equality perspective, yes, but with only the last check, there is the possibility that the code to follow will dereference `null`.

Comment: @Ani: You are right; I was thinking about Equals(object obj) where this cannot happen. Some people do the multiple checking there as well though.

Comment: @Ani, @Skurmedel, is the order of the three `ReferenceEquals` checks wrong?  If you pass in 2 nulls, either of the first two will (incorrectly) return false, so the third will never get reached.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: That is a good point, I agree with you. Maybe the OP didn't want `null Equals null` ? Just speculating..

Comment: @Jared. That while.Contains(a) did not fix it, although it is still likely that the problem is indeed with the Allocation or Resource object. An allocation has a reference to both an Activity and a Resource, and I have just started refactoring all three objects from Entity semantics to Value Object semantics. I just started with the Activity one, and I can use the LINQ code for now and revisit this when I am further along. I still find it confusing that Contains works as expected and Remove doesn't tho. Cheers and an up-vote, since you obviously need more points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code that "works" appears to look at `StartTime` and `Resource` while ignoring `Activity`, whereas your `IEqualityComparer<Allocation>` implementation looks at all three. Could your problem be related to that?

Also: are your `StartTime`, `Resource`, and `Activity` properties unchanging? Otherwise, since they affect your `GetHashCode` result, I think you run the risk of breaking your `HashSet<Allocation>`.

Comment: Bingo on the first line. I'm not quite sure if it was some sort of recursion, but it is an Activity that owns the HashSet in this case. Placing a guard in the add allocation method (ClockIn) to check the allocation belongs to 'this' activity and taking Activity out of the comparer methods is more logical in any event and fixes the problem by returning a consistent hash. Cheers!